# Bluetooth Keyboard not pairing 14.04/Lxle

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I know this question has been asked before and i have spent all day looking at those solutions but they are not helping!

On Lenovo G50-30 connecting H-Write mini bluetooth keyboard.
The keyboard shows up in Bluetooth manager, i click setup, it prompts for a pin i create one, it tries to pair asking for the pin to be entered on the device. then just times out, "could not add device". I then get a pop up asking for the pin, it does not confirm connection, the Device list shows its connected and the keyboard works for about 20 seconds, then the popup returns, once again asking for the pin, i get 20 secs and around we go.
After leaving it a while if i try and use the keyboard the pin pop-up comes straight back, like its waiting for the pin.
It seems as if the pin is not recognized? perhaps there is a file i could edit to enter it manually?
I tried removing the device and starting again with a different pin, same problem.

I have headphones that connect with no problem so i think its just the pin not accepted.

Some posts suggest installing Gnome-bluetooth, would that replace my current blueman or is it actually the same? i had a lot of trouble setting it up in the first place due to idea-pad adapter,i've now removed, so am reluctant to change anything unnecessarily!

Thanks for any help, Tony

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing gnome-bluetooth as it seems blueman has issues pairing with keyboards.  I just tested blueman with my Logitech K480 keyboard and it was a total failure, with gnome-bluetooth it put a pin on the screen and acknowledged the entry on the keyboard and paired successfully.  This was with Ubuntu 15.10 but I doubt the results will be different

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31 i think i'll have to try that yes, i'm feeling that it must be something simple if i get 20 seconds typing, but can't fathom it, new to linux, cheers.